# mvprintw() only printing partially

Tags: c, linux, ncurses

I've just migrated to Ubuntu and I'm trying to get adapted to curses and ncurses. I'm trying to build a simple that use the arrows to navigate, uses Q to exit and a help with F2. The problem is, after showing the help text, when it go backs to the initial menu it only prints the initial parts of the mvprintw. Here's my code:

***CODE UPDATED***

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <locale.h>
#include <ncurses.h>

#define MIN 1
#define MAX 6

//STRUCT PARA ARMEZAR DADOS PARA CADASTRO
typedef struct{
    char nome[50];
    long int rg;
    char cpf[11];
    unsigned short idade;
    float alt;
}REGISTRO;

REGISTRO dados;

//Inicialização da função cadastro
void cadastro(REGISTRO *dados);

int main(){
    short c, opc, x, y;

    char path[] = "data/";
    char pathA[] = "data/dados.bin";

    setlocale(LC_ALL, "");
    initscr();
    raw();
    noecho();
    keypad(stdscr, TRUE);

    FILE *data;

    if(!mkdir(path, 0777)){
        printf("Pasta \"data\" nao encontrada.\nCriando diretório...\n");
    }

    if((data = fopen(pathA, "r+"))==NULL){
        printf("Não foi possivel encontrar o arquivo dados.bin!\nUm novo arquivo será criado...\n");
        if((data = fopen(pathA, "w+"))==NULL){
            printf("Não foi possivel criar o arquivo.\nO programa será finalizado em breve!\n");
            exit(1);
        }
    }

    do{
        erase();
        mvprintw(0,0,"-----DATABASE EVIL CORP-----\n");
        printw("1. Cadastro\n2. Whatever\n3. Whatever\n4. Whatever\n5. Whatever\n6. Whatever\n");
        x = 0; y = 1; opc = 1;
        refresh();
        do{
            mvprintw(7,0,"OPC: %hd", opc);
            mvprintw(8,0,"C: %hd", c);
            move(y,x);
            c = getch();

            if(c == 'Q' || c == 'q'){
                opc=0;
                c=0;
            }

            if(c == KEY_F(2)){
                erase();
                mvprintw(0, 0, "MENU DE AJUDA");
                x = 0, y = 1, opc = 0;
                refresh();
                getch();
            }

            if(c == '\n'){
                switch(opc){
                    case 1:
                        erase();
                        cadastro(&dados);
                        getch();
                        opc=0;
                    break;

                    case 2:
                        erase();
                        printw("TESTE");
                        getch();
                        opc=0;
                    break;

                    default:
                        erase();
                        mvprintw(0,0, "Opcao invalida ou ainda em construcao.");
                        getch();
                        opc=0;
                    break;
                }
            }

            switch(c){
                case KEY_UP:
                    if(opc>1){
                        opc--;
                        y--;
                    }

                    else{
                        opc=MAX;
                        y=MAX;
                    }
                break;

                case KEY_DOWN:
                    if(opc<6){
                        opc++;
                        y++;
                    }
                    else{
                        opc=MIN;
                        y=MIN;
                    }
            }

        }while(opc);
    }while(c);

    endwin();
    return 0;
}

void cadastro(REGISTRO *dados){
    erase();
    mvprintw(0, 0, "-----REGISTRO DE DADOS-----\nNome: ");
    refresh();
    fgets(dados->nome, sizeof(dados->nome), stdin);
    printw("RG: ");
    scanf("%ld", &dados->rg);
    fflush(stdin);
    printw("CPF: ");
    fgets(dados->cpf, sizeof(dados->cpf), stdin);
    printw("Altura: ");
    scanf("%f", &dados->alt);
    printw("Idade: ");
    scanf("%hd", &dados->idade);
}
```

Edited: New problem, when I go in the cadastro() function, I can't see what I'm doing as input but somehow I know something is happening can after pressing random keys I can get back to the first menu and everything goes back to normal. I think it's related to the ncurses screen, but I'm not sure about it.

Comment: That's a separate question: the keys do not echo because you turned echo off during initialization using `noecho();`

Comment: Yeah, I finally fixed most of the error. First I changed the fgets to getnstr, I don't know yet but ncurses has some problems with stdin. And I simply activated echo in the beginning of my function and turned it off again at the end of it.  My real problem wasn't with the echoing but with the fact that the fgets and scanf wasn't working as intended to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the program runs a shell process "clear" without doing [`endwin`](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_initscr.3x.html#h3-endwin) to tell ncurses that it is leaving screen mode temporarily.  Use the [erase()](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_clear.3x.html) function.

If you replace `system("clear")` with `erase()`, it will behave as you intended.

Comment: Thanks, it really helped with my problem but now I'm having another problem that I don't if it's related or not with the first. I think it's something with the ncurses screen. I'll update the first topic so you can see if it's related.